# can I use SRGS grammar and Speech Recognition to develop my software in Vietnamese speech

Tags: windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, dictation

I'm developing a windows phone 8 software that support Vietnamese people to correct their voice. I have researched that can use SRGS grammar to help architect complex voice interaction with my apps. So can I use SRGS grammar and Speech Recognition to develop my software in Vietnamese speech?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out this link for language support for Windows Phone 8

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202918(v=vs.105).aspx

Also I would like to add that you can create grammar (SRGS grammar) for Vietnamese and for speech recognition.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361675(v=office.14).aspx